# Building gcc: libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.72)

Tags: linux, gcc, libstdc++, build-error, symbol-not-found

I'm trying to build an older version of GCC, on a system with newer versions of GCC. During the build, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/src/gcc-6.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.72)
```

Does this mean that I have to build libicu myself using an older version of libstdc++ (which I don't have)? If not - how can I work around this problem?

my distribution is Devuan GNU/Linux Excalibur; default GCC version is 13.2.0.